# Metal, X-Ray, Gamma-ray

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, x-rays, gamma-rays

As I know, all metals absorb x-ray and gamma radiation. Also, as I know, all rays are converted into any energy. In this case, I mean warmth.

For example, an x-ray is absorbed by metal, then metal had to become warmer. But we have the opposite.
Medics who have a lead apron don't take them off immediately after they end the x-ray research of the patient, 'cause it does not warm.

I have two versions "Why?":

1. X-Rays have no such power for a warm apron.
2. X-Rays have no time for a warm apron.

I think that gamma-ray has the same effect. That's warm metal.

Questions, Am I right:

1. ...X-Rays have to warm metal?
2. ...why X-Rays does not warm lead apron?
3. ...Gamma-Rays have to warm metal?

Please, correct my mind if I'm wrong and explain where I make mistakes. I'm a dilettante in physics.

Comment: 1 mSv of radiation dose corresponds to 0.001 J/kg. How much warmer would you expect does that heat the metal?

Comment: @Loong  IIn my example, I think about 30-40 degrees Celsius for a person to feel. Is it possible? Perhaps, X-Rays or gamma-rays have to more powerful, what will be impossible for use in medicine, IMHO... It's all my guesses.

Comment: Run the numbers. 1 Gy (100 rad) is 1J/kg of absorbed energy. Presuming you are mostly water at 4.186 J/gm/C, 1 Gy raises your body temperature by roughly .00025C. Note that 10Gy whole body is “almost invariably fatal”, and that isn’t from heating. Cancer radiation treatments are typically in the 10s of Gy, localized, and over a time period of weeks.

Comment: @JonCuster Thanks. I see that in general my thought goes into truth direction but except one thing - metal is warmed but very, very, very a little. Apparently, in that case, waves are transformed not only warm energy.